# Stationary element of matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, stdvector

I'm trying to write a function which will check if matrix has (at least one) stationary elements. An element of a matrix is stationary if its value is equal to the value of the elements located to the left, right, above and below it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
bool Stationary(std::vector < std::vector < int >> a) {
  int total_elements = 0, rows = a.size();
  int up, down, left, right;
  for (auto i: a)
    for (auto j: i)
      total_elements++;
  if (total_elements % rows)
    throw std::range_error("Ragged matrix");
  int columns = total_elements / rows;
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      up = a[i][j + 1];
      down = a[i][j - 1];
      right = a[i + 1][j];
      left = a[i - 1][j];
      std::cout << up << " " << down << " " << right << " " << left << " " << a[i][j] << "\n";
      if (up == down == right == left == a[i][j]) return true;
    }
  return false;
}
int main() {
   std::vector<std::vector<int>>a{
      {2,1,3},
      {1,1,1},
      {4,1,5}};
  try {
    if (Stationary(a))
      std::cout << "Yes";
    else std::cout << "No";
  } catch (std::range_error e) {
    std::cout << e.what();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Problem with my code is access to random elements that are not integral parts of the matrix, because with the command  i+1 or j+1 I go beyond the frame of the matrix. Could you help me to modify this without leaving the matrix frame?

Comment: Can't you loop from index `1` to `size()-2` (inclusive)? There's no point in checking the coordinates at the edges anyway, is there?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it doesn't help anyhow, nothing would be printed

Comment: yes it does help: https://godbolt.org/z/M36qxa4fh

Comment: maybe you can you show the code where you do loop from 1 to size()-2 (inclusive) so we can help to fix it. The issue in the code you did post you already found, but it is not clear why you say the fix would not help

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number why do you start loop at i=1 and j=1? in that way you skip first row and first column

Comment: did you understand Teds comment? The issue is that you try to check elements that have no down/up/right or top element. Looping only from index `1` to `size()-2` checks only elements that have 4 neighbours

Comment: @RocketProcd I think you should have worked this out with pencil and paper before writing any code.  It should have been obvious that edge elements require special consideration.  If it's a case of "I don't care, I will write anything to get most of the cases, and leave it for someone to add the extra logic", well, StackOverflow doesn't or shouldn't work that way.

Comment: there cannot be a "stationary element" in the first row or first column when "stationary" means that it has a `top` and a `left` element

Comment: on the other hand it is unclear if a stationary element necessarily needs 4 neighbor elements. Can there be a stationary element in the first row? Can you give an example for this case?

Comment: asked differently, does the matrix with a single element `{{1}}` have a stationary element?

Comment: thank you very much, I understand now, if anyone of you posts answer, I would accept it

Comment: you should clarify the question. As it stands the question is unclear. What you need to clarify is what I asked before: Does a stationary element need 4 neighbors?

Comment: `element of a matrix is stationary if its value is equal to the value of the elements located to the left, right, above and below it.` so this means it must have 4 neighbors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you check the edges of the matrix and in a position like `a[0][0]` you step out of bounds when checking `a[-1][0]` and `a[0][-1]`. Instead start your loops at `1` and end at `size() - 2` (inclusive).

Another suggestion is to not take the matrix *by-value* which copies the whole matrix. Take it by `const&` instead.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

bool Stationary(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& a) {
    // with less than 3 rows, it can't have 4 neighbours (left, right, above, below):
    if (a.size() < 3) return false; 

    size_t cols = a[0].size();
    
    for (size_t i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i)
        if (a[i].size() != cols) throw std::range_error("Ragged matrix");

    // start at 1 and end at size() - 2:
    for (size_t y = 1; y < a.size() - 1; ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 1; x < cols - 1; ++x) {

            int value = a[y][x];

            if (value == a[y - 1][x] &&
                value == a[y + 1][x] &&
                value == a[y][x - 1] &&
                value == a[y][x + 1]) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a{{2, 1, 3},
                                    {1, 1, 1},
                                    {4, 1, 5}};
                                    
    std::cout << Stationary(a) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: try with matrix `a{{2,1,3},{1,1,1},{4,1,5,9}};` it won't throw an exception, you should count all elements and divide with rows, or something similar to check if matrix is square

Comment: @RocketProcd Yes, that throws an exception.  Did you install a `try`/`catch` ?

Comment: sorry, I didn't saw for loop that checks every row of matrix, I'm tired right now so I missed it accidentally

Comment: @RocketProcd :-) No worries!